# Continous minimum velocity tracking of a finger on a sprite in spritekit/ios

Tags: sprite-kit, sprite, uigesturerecognizer, swipe, gesture

What is a good way to continuously track the velocity of a user moving their finger up and down on a sprite without lifting the finger? And if they don't go fast enough(set a minimum) to perform an action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some code you can use to drag a sprite across the screen at different speeds depending on your finger acceleration.  You can add your own code to detect the magnitude of change and perform whichever action you want..

[image]

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    // time values
    var delta:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(0)
    var last_update_time:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(0)

    // our sprite
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 30))

    // tracking difference between touches
    var currentTouchY: CGFloat = CGFloat(0)
    var lastTouchY: CGFloat = CGFloat(0)

    // the magnitude of change between current and last touch
    var forceMag: CGFloat = CGFloat(0)
    // max mag so our sprite doesnt travel at crazy speed
    let forceMagMax: CGFloat = CGFloat(7)
    // direction of our sprites travel
    var forceDir: CGFloat = CGFloat(0)
    // arbitrary speed we want sprite to move
    let velocity: CGFloat = CGFloat(70)

    // we use this to stop moving our sprite when we let go
    var intervalsWithoutChange = 0

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        sprite.position.x = 100
        sprite.position.y = size.width/2
        self.addChild(sprite)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let yCoord = location.y

            lastTouchY = yCoord
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let yCoord = location.y

            intervalsWithoutChange = 0
            currentTouchY = yCoord
            let diff = currentTouchY - lastTouchY
            forceMag = abs(diff)
            forceMag = forceMag > forceMagMax ? forceMagMax : forceMag
            forceDir = diff < 0 ? -1 : 1
            lastTouchY = yCoord
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        intervalsWithoutChange = 1
        currentTouchY = 0
        lastTouchY = 0
    }

    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

        if last_update_time == 0.0 {
            delta = 0
        } else {
            delta = currentTime - last_update_time
        }

        last_update_time = currentTime

        if intervalsWithoutChange > 0 {
            forceMag -= CGFloat(15) * CGFloat(delta)
        }

        if forceMag < 0.01 {
            forceMag = 0
        }

        let change = forceDir * pow(forceMag, 1.29)

        sprite.position.y += change * CGFloat(delta) * velocity
    }
}
```